# How to save many data tables to one file using tFDMemTable

Tags: delphi, firedac

I imported many Excel worksheets to many tFDMemTables one by one and modified them. Now I try to save them to any kind of ONE file to maintain with tFDMemTable further, no more Excel. How can I make many tFDMemTables to ONE object to save to ONE file, not by APPEND?

I use Delphi 10.3 Community in Windows 10. The reference recommends FireDAC that I use it.

In .Net I make multi table layers into ONE DataSet and ONE XML file with the following simple code. But in Delphi it seems that a data table means a data set. So what is that holds many data tables like .Net DataSet?

```
DataSet.Tables.Add(Table);

DataSet.WriteXml(FileName);
```

Comment: You say " to maintain with tFDMemTable further, no more Excel.".  Saving a number of Excel workbooks to a single FireDAC table is easy enough, but how do you envisage "maintaining" Excel workbooks **without** using Excel?  Perhaps I do not understand exactly what you want to do; please explain.

Comment: @MartynA Yes exactly. I don't need to use Excel file after the import to tFDMemTable. Thanks always.

Comment: So is my answer the kind of thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below shows how to save a series of Excel files (workbooks) into rows
 of an FDMemTable on the basis of one workbook per FDMemTable row.  This is done
 by saving the Excel file in a blob field of the FDMemTable.

The GetFiles method shows how to scan a folder for Excel files and save them to
 the FDMemTable using the SaveFile method.  The FDMemTable row includes the name
 of the Excel file and the path to where it was found.

When the GetExcelMethod completes, it saves the FDMemTable contents to a file
 which can then be copied elsewhere.

The WriteFiles method reads the Excel files from the FDMemTable and writes them
 to a specified directory:  this method also shows how to open the file using Excel.

Of course, the techniques shown here are not restricted to Excel files:  by
 adjusting the file mask in the GetFiles, it could find and save files of any type.

```
  uses [...]  ShellAPI;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    [...]
    private
      ID : Integer;  //  used to generate iD field for FDMemTable1
      [...]
    public
    end;

  procedure TForm1.GetFiles(Path : String);
  //  Find all files in a given directory and save them to FDMemTable1
  var
    SearchRec : TSearchRec;
    Res : Integer;
    FN : String;
  begin
    Path := Path + '\*.xl*';
    Res := FindFirst(Path, faAnyFile, SearchRec);
    if Res = 0 {SearchRec.Attr and faAnyFile = faAnyFile} then begin
      repeat
        SaveFile(ExtractFilePath(Path) + SearchRec.Name);
        Res := FindNext(SearchRec);
      until Res <> 0;
      FindClose(SearchRec);
      FN := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Excelfiles.XML';
      FDMemTable1.SaveToFile(FN, sfXML);
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.SaveFile(FileName : String);
  //  Save an individual file to FDMemTable1
  var
    APath,
    AName : String;
  begin
    APath := ExtractFilePath(FileName);
    AName := ExtractFileName(FileName);

    inc(ID);
    FDMemTable1.Insert;
    FDMemTable1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := ID;
    FDMemTable1.FieldByName('FilePath').AsString := APath;
    FDMemTable1.FieldByName('FileName').AsString := AName;
    TBlobField(FDMemTable1.FieldByName('FileData')).LoadFromFile(FileName);
    FDMemTable1.Post;

  end;

  procedure TForm1.WriteFiles;
  //  Extract files from FDMemTable1 to s given directory
  var
    FileName : String;
  begin
    if not FDMemTable1.Active then
      FDMemTable1.Open;
    FDMemTable1.First;
    while not FDMemTable1.Eof do begin
      FileName := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('FileName').AsString;
      TBlobField(FDMemTable1.FieldByName('FileData')).SaveToFile('C:\Temp\'+ FileName);
      // Uncomment the following line to have the file opened in Excel; you'll need to add ShellAPI to your Uses list
      // ShellExecute(Handle, 'Open', PChar('C:\Temp\' + Filename), '','',SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      FDMemTable1.Next;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    FieldDef : TFieldDef;
  begin
    ID := 0;
    FieldDef := FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    FieldDef.Name := 'ID';
    FieldDef.DataType := ftInteger;

    FieldDef := FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    FieldDef.Name := 'FilePath';
    FieldDef.DataType := ftString;
    FieldDef.Size := Max_Path;

    FieldDef := FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    FieldDef.Name := 'FileName';
    FieldDef.DataType := ftString;
    FieldDef.Size := Max_Path;

    FieldDef := FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    FieldDef.Name := 'FileData';
    FieldDef.DataType := ftBlob;

    FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    GetFiles('D:\aaad7\aaaofficeauto');
  end;

  procedure TForm1.btnWriteFilesClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    WriteFiles;
  end;
```

Comment: This perfectly works. What I try is not just to import many Excel files but to handle many tables with 1 file at once. So I changed 'file' in the code to 'tMemoryStream' and I have found that 1 tFDMemTable can hold many tables in itself with blob. It is more complex than .net way but more poweful and amazing. I heartily appreciate again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know another way. Append all data into a new dataset and export it using SaveToFile() procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you.

Use `TFDDataSet` variable to store all data from Excel files.

```
DataSet: TFDDataSet
```

Each time you get a data table, merge it into the `DataSet` via [TFDDataSet.MergeDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.MergeDataSet) method.

```
// Getting data from Excel files.
// Suppose there are 10 excel files.
for I := 0 to 9 do
begin
  // Stored Excel data to TempDataSet.
  // ...

  // Merge TempDataSet to DataSet.
  DataSet.MergeDataSet(TempDataSet, dmDataAppend, mmAdd);
end;
```

Finally, use [TFDDataSet.SaveToFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SaveToFile) method to write XML file.

```
// Write to XML file.
DataSet.SaveToFile('C:\Data\DataSetData.xml', sfXML);
```

Comment: Fields of each Excel worksheet are different from those of other worksheets. When I retrieve the merged file, is the original structure preserved?

Comment: You must have the same data structure in each dataset to merge them